# Django, how to make a query with [ORDER BY CONVERT (name USING gbk) ASC]

Tags: mysql, django

I want to make a query with [`ORDER BY CONVERT (name USING gbk) ASC`] ,so that `foreignkey` list in admin change/add form can be sorted by Chinese Pinyin , is it possible?

DB: mysql , 
Sample class are blow (Character sets of table commoninfo : `utf8_general_ci`):

```
class CommonInfo(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Personal(CommonInfo):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=128,null=True, blank=True, default = None)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=128,null=True, blank=True, default = None)

class Profile(models.Model):
    personal_info = models.ForeignKey(Personal, null=True, blank=True, default = None)
    mobile = models.CharField(max_length=32,default='',null=True, blank=True)
```

I tried below 2 methods in ProfileAdmin but neither works

```
def formfield_for_foreignkey(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
    if db_field.name == "personal_info":    

        #raw_sql = 'SELECT id as commoninfo_ptr_id, name FROM share_commoninfo ORDER BY CONVERT (name USING gbk) ASC'
        #raw_querySet = Personal.objects.raw(raw_sql) 
        #kwargs["queryset"] = raw_querySet

        querySet = Personal.objects.extra(order_by=['CONVERT (name USING gbk)'])
        kwargs["queryset"] = querySet

        return super(ProfileAdmin, self).formfield_for_foreignkey(db_field, request, **kwargs)

admin.site.register(models.Profile, ProfileAdmin)
```

> FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'CONVERT (name USING gbk)' into
>   field. Choices are: commoninfo_ptr, commoninfo_ptr_id, first_name, id,
>   last_name, name, profile, Check fields/fieldsets/exclude attributes of
>   class ProfileAdmin.

Comment: why need `'CONVERT (name USING gbk)'` ?

Comment: Table’s character set is utf8_general_ci which cannot get correct(expected) order by using [ORDER BY chinese_data_field],
It seems that to have the expect order – order by Chinese Pinyin , I have to either covert the table to gbk, or covert the order field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from django.db.models import Func, Value

class Convert(Func):
    def __init__(self, expression, transcoding_name, **extra):
         super(Convert, self).__init__(
             expression, transcoding_name=Value(transcoding_name), **extra)

    def as_mysql(self, compiler, connection):
        self.function = 'CONVERT'
        self.template = '%(function)s(%(expressions)s AS %(transcoding_name)s)'
        return super(Conver, self).as_sql(compiler, connection)
```

Usage:

```
queryset.order_by(Convert('name', 'gbk').asc())
```

Documentation:

- [`Func()` expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/expressions/#func-expressions)
- [Examples of database functions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/_modules/django/db/models/functions/#Length)

Comment: Thank you so much, the code works so well, and I learnt more from the documentation: )

Comment: All is well except for two things: 1. the argument `transcoding_name` mustn't be wrapped in `Value()` in `__init__()`. 2. The keyword in the template between `%(expressions)s` and `%(transcoding_name)s` should be `USING`, not `AS`.

Answer (score 1):

you can use [extra](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#extra)

```
queryset.extra(
    select={'convert_name': 'convert(name using gbk)'}, 
    order_by=['convert_name']
)
```